# service with android:process doesn't startService

Tags: android

I have problem. I Just startService MyService.

with `android:process=":remote"` can't startService.

if I delete `android:precess=":remote"` it appears it's not the problem.

What is the problem?

```
<service
   android:name=".MyService"
   android:enabled="true"
   android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
   android:process=":remote">
   <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
   </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: What is need of `android:process=":remote"` in your case?

Comment: It retrieves information about other apps running in the device and stores the data on the server. @MilindMevada